# Inline editable list of objects in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a list of `Person`

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  birthdate: Date;
}
```

I successfully display this list like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthdate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
            <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ person.birthdate }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I would like to make the field `name` editable inline and to make the field `birthdate` editable with datepicker popup.
I would also need validation and the modifications will trigger a web api call.
What is the best way to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add text input or datepicker in td like this

in html file

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Birthdate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
            <td><input type="text" (input)="onValueChange(person.name)" [(ngModel)]="person.name"/></td>
            <td><input type="date" [(ngModel)]="person.birthdate"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

ts

```
onValueChange(value:any){
  //this api call or whatever you need to do on value change
}
```

or you can use other angular based components like [primeng](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit) or [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/)

Comment: thanks for your example and your 2 links. I used PrimeNg table edit which is easy to use and fit to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [ReactiveForm with a formArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and use the [mydatepicker library](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker) for the datepicker. The documentations are well described but if you have any question I'll answer asap ! Here is a good tutorial too : https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Comment: thanks for your answer. The tuto is very interesting.